# Why visual constraints not supporting UITableViewAutomaticDimension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

When i tried with constraints via storyboard its working perfectly .

[image]

this is my view controller.

[image]

When i was tried with visual constraints i am getting screen like this .

[image]

**this is my visual constraints :**

```
NSDictionary *viewsdictionary=@{@"txtview":cell.txtview,
                                    @"lbldate":cell.lbldate};
    [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[txtview]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsdictionary]];
    [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[lbldate]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsdictionary]];
    [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[txtview]-10-[lbldate(200@1000)]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsdictionary]];
    if([from isEqualToString:_tophonenumber])
    {

        cell.txtview.layer.borderWidth=2.0;
        cell.txtview.layer.borderColor=[UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
        [cell.contentView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-[lbldate]-10-[txtview]-|" options:0 metrics:nil views:viewsdictionary]];

    }
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:YES];
    self.tableview.estimatedRowHeight = 160;
    self.tableview.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
 }
```

for some reason i am changing the txtview and label but thats also not changing what i did wrong ?

Help me to over come this problem thanks :)

Comment: Constraints are cumulative & do not override to each other. if you have an existing constraint, setting another constraint of the same type does not override the previous one.

As I can see in you code, you are adding lots of constraints on contentView of cell and tableView cell's are reused so there are lots of changes that you are adding constraints on a cell again and again.

But In case Of Interface Builder I add all constraints once at the time of cell object initialise.

Comment: @keshavvishwkarma what is the best way to do it ?

Comment: adding constraints from Interface Builder is the best & easy way, but there are some constraints that are not possible from Interface Builder(those are changes at run time), for them we have to add constraints programmatically.

Comment: To add programmatically constraints easily, you should try  https://github.com/keshavvishwkarma/KVConstraintExtensionsMaster library.

Answer (score 0):

In your IB constraints, I assume that your date has a fixed width, while your text box has a variable width and is just asked to stick to the date leading edge, with the date only adhering from trailing edge to superview trailing?  In your programmatic constraints, you do not give that date the fixed width unless a string if statement is satisfied, right?  So otherwise, the date has not got the constraints it needs.

Also though, do you call [cell layoutIfNeeded] after updating the constraints?  They might need that as well, if you update the constraints on cellForRowAtIndexPath.  Theres also a final thing you might need to do with the UITableView so that the table is updated :

```
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

If you call this after updating cell constraints, it ensures that the tableview cells are all re-aligned correctly (particular if the height has changed).  But I wouldnt call that after each cell has changed - do it once when the tableview has finished updating.

Comment: because of the conflict constraints this problem arise ?

Comment: Constraints are hard!  You have to really carefully pick through every detail to ensure they are the same, ie between your visual ones and your programmatic ones.  Go through it with a fine-tooth comb :)